# User restrictions- field comparision

Tags: users

In my site, I have various fields for user registration along with image captcha. Though I get fake registrations at least 3 per day. I found that "**username**" and "**address**" fields are **identical** by value in all those registrations. Is there any way to **deny access** to those registrations?.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Botcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/botcha). This will effectively prevent bot submissions. Don't use short term adjustments for Drupal defaults unless you've used your site for long time.